# Parallel processing using xargs - optimizing shell script

Tags: shell, parallel-processing, xargs, gnu-parallel

Parallel processing using xargs - takes too much time ( ~8 hrs) on some servers

I have a script that scans an entire file system and does some processing on a selective bunch of files. I am using xargs to do this in parallel. Using xargs instead of using GNU parallel is because I will have to run this script on 100s of servers and installing the utility on all the servers is not an option.

All the servers have the below configuration

Architecture:          x86_64
CPU(s):                24
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    6
Socket(s):             2

I tried increasing the number of processes but beyond a point that doesn't help. I read somewhere that if the script is I/O bound, its better to keep the number of processes equal to the number of cores. Is that true?

```sh
find . -type f ! -empty -print0 | xargs -L1 -P 10 -0 "./process.sh"
```

I believe the above code will make my script I/O bound?

I have to scan the entire file system. How do I optimize the code so I can significantly reduce the processing time.

Also, my code only needs to handle parallel processing of files in a file system. Processing the servers in parallel is taken care of.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find where your bottleneck is.

From your question it is unclear that you have found where your bottleneck is.

If it is CPU then you can use our 100 servers with GNU Parallel without install GNU Parallel on all of them (are you by the way aware of `parallel --embed` available since 20180322?)

You simply prefix the sshlogins with number of CPU threads and /. So for 24 threads:

```
find ... | 
  parallel -S 24/server1,24/server2,24/server3 command
```

If your bottleneck is your disk, then using more servers will not help.

Then it is better to get a faster disk (e.g. SSD, mirrored disks, RAM-disks and similar).

The optimal number of threads to use on a disk can in practice not be predicted. It can only be measured. I have had a 40 spindle RAID system where the optimal number was 10 threads.

Comment: I believe the bottleneck here is I/O. Please correct me if I am wrong. 
I have edited my question. I only need to process files in a file system in parallel. Running multiple servers in parallel is taken care of.

Comment: @Archana If you cannot upgrade the hardware, then the best advice is to start with 1 thread. Measure. Increase with 1 thread. Measure again. Until you reach the optimal number of threads.

Comment: I tried using GNU parallel but it seems much slower. Not sure what am I doing wrong here. 
    `find / -type f ! -empty -print0 | parallel -L1 -j 8 -0 "./process.sh"`
L1 because I want to pass one file to the script.